# Maximum weighted subgraph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

**Problem:** Given a graph G with positive integral weights on nodes as well as edges, find an induced subgraph H with maximum total weight per node, i.e., the goal is to maximize
$$
\frac{ \sum_{e \in H}w(e) + \sum_{v \in H} w(v) }{|V(H)|}.$$

If you allow negative weights, then it is NP-hard (easy reduction from Clique). I have a strong feeling that the above is not NP-Hard.

I would love to have some first-thoughts on the above, if not a full-fledged optimal algorithm. Does it seem to be NP-Hard? What is the closest known problem -- my thoughts were Prize Collection, Clique -- but both seem much harder.

Comment: Isn't G the induced subgraph of G with maximal weight?

Comment: @qz no, you want the subgraph that maximizes average weight (... so to speak)

Comment: Have a look at the [**Dense Subgraph Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_subgraph).

Comment: @PålGD ah, thanks for editing the question to be more clear

Comment: Yes, I see that "dense subgraph problem" is very close. Thanks -- that should work.

Comment: @PålGD, but that problem, unconstrained on the number of vertices, has a poly time solution. Do you feel like this is also the case here?

Comment: @PålGD Can this problem be approached greedily? I.e. repeatedly removing the node which contributes the least to the graph weight (node weight + edge weights).

Comment: If you manage to solve your problem, please write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Dense Subgraph Problem (thanks @PalGD) is a special case of the above problem--with no node weights and unit edge weights. See the solutions for the dense subgraph problem [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.1184&rep=rep1&type=pdf). These solutions (LP and 2-approximation Greedy) easily generalize to the above problem (generalizing LP requires a bit of understanding/effort, but generalizing Greedy is trivial).